# docker pull sebp/elk authentication error: authentication required

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

I am trying to pull the sebp/elk repository from the DockerHub but I keep getting an `authentication error: authentication required`

[image]

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: can you provide the pom.xml  file? Also can you do `docker login` on your machine. Also can you perform a pull manually `docker pull sebp/elk`?

Comment: yes I can do `docker login`. When I do `docker pull sebp/elk` sometimes it goes through but sometimes I also get `authentication error`

Comment: do you have some private registry that you are sometimes using? public image on dockerhub do not require a login.

Comment: yes I have some private registries that am using

Comment: I suspect that the maven plugin is trying to download the image from the private registry. Have you configured the registry credentials as described here https://dmp.fabric8.io/#pull-vs-push-authentication